Sqlalchemy 2 | Polymorphic relation
I am using SQLchemy 2. I have a portfolio and comment model. I have established such a polymorphic relationship so that I can write comments to both the portfolio and the comment. I need to store the comments written to both the portfolio and the portfolio in 1 table in the db. I'm not sure if the relationships are correct.
How can I get the comments of both the portfolio and the comments written in the portfolio by using a polymorphic relationship?
Portfolio model:
class Portfolio(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'portfolio_portfolio'
    id: Mapped[intpk]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user_user.id'))
    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='portfolios')
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    
    comments:Mapped[list['Comment']] = relationship(
        'Comment',
        primaryjoin="and_(Portfolio.id == Comment.commentable_id,\
        Comment.commentable_type=='portfolio_portfolio')",
    )
    

Comment model:
class Comment(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'core_comment'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user_user.id'))
    commentable_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    commentable_id: Mapped[int]
    text: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'core_comment',
        'polymorphic_on': commentable_type,
    }

Polymorphically related models:
class PortfolioComment(Comment):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': Portfolio.__tablename__,
    }

class CommentComment(Comment):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'comment_comment',
    }

